# Solution to $\langle p, f(p)\rangle = h(p)$ for known $h$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have $\langle p, f(p)\rangle = h(p)$, where $p$ belongs to the $n>1$ dimensional simplex $\Delta$. Suppose that $f$ is continuously differentiable, and $h$ is known for $p\in \Delta$. Is it possible to solve for $f(p)$? Is there a unique solution to $f$?

Comment: Is $\langle p, f(p)\rangle$ the usual inner product?

Comment: no uniqueness. in $\mathbb R^3,$ any solution $f(p)$ can be altered to $f(p) + p \times g(p)$ with the traditional cross product and any $g(p)$ you like

Comment: @JohnMa yes, it is the usual inner product.

Comment: @WillJagy, thanks Will! I think this indeed rules out uniqueness.